Is it true that if $p$ is a prime of the form $4n+1$ then it can be written as $(x²+y²) /(x+y)$ where $x, y$ are distinct positive integers?
It's well known that a prime of the form $4n+1$ is the sum of $2$ squares. But I stumbled across this slight variation and I have absolutely no idea how to prove it; I'm not even sure if this is true.

Don't forget that x, y are distinct

Seems to be true for the first $10,000$ primes of the given form and for some other numbers.  For instance $10 = \frac{4^2 + 12^2}{4+12}$.  In fact, it seems that 70-75% of integers have a representation in the given form with distinct $x$ and $y$.  (I only call out the last feature because of a mental error in my now deleted comment(s).)

if I call the number $n,$ the correct restriction is that $n$ be divisible by at least one prime $r \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Its truly a shame that more effort wasn't put in by the OP in writing this question up to meet the MSE Guidelines [tour]. It is interesting indeed...

If $p=X^2+Y^2$, then $p=\dfrac{((X+Y)X)^2+((X+Y)Y)^2}{(X+Y)X+(X+Y)Y}$,
so take $x=(X+Y)X$ and $y=(X+Y)Y$.

Later, to show how I got here:  the integer equation $x^2 + y^2 - nx - ny=0,$   upon completing both squares, becomes
$$ \color{red} {(2x-n)^2 + ( 2y - n)^2 = 2 n^2 }  $$
The method below can be done for every number $n$  divisible by at least one prime $r \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$  Furthermore, in the long run, the density of numbers that are not divisible by any prime $r \equiv 1 \pmod 4$  is zero, see displayed formula,  from sum of prime reciprocals  Does the sum of reciprocals of primes congruent to $1 \mod{4}$ diverge?
$$\sum_{\substack{p \equiv a \bmod b \\ p \leq X}} \frac{1}{p} \; \; \; \; 
= \; \;  \frac{1}{\varphi(b)}  \; \log \log X + O(1)
$$
That is, the set of numbers which have at least one prime factor $r \equiv 1 \pmod 4$  has full density.
Given such an $n$
we can arrange $$ n^2 = u^2 + v^2  $$
with integers $u > v > 0.$
Then simply take
$$   \color{magenta} { x = \frac{n+u+v}{2}, } $$
$$  \color{teal} { y = \frac{n+u-v}{2} } $$
to achieve
$$   \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x+y}  = n$$
With my calculations, I got
$$  2(x^2 + y^2) = n^2 + 2un + u^2 + v^2  =  n^2 + 2un + n^2 = 2 n^2 + 2un $$
and
$$ 2 (x+y) = 2n+2u  $$
so that
$   \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x+y}  = n$
Various notes:  any integer $k$ we have $k^2 \equiv k \pmod 2.$

Yea, I figured it out. I should have replaced $u^2+v^2$ with $n^2$, instead of the other way around.
